# Function Undefined: Must a javascript function be defined within the same file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs, undefined-reference

I've got a file `notifications.js` containing one event bound to an element, and a function `updateNotification()`. This function uses jQuery to update certain elements on the page when a JSON object is passed as a parameter.

**The problem:**

I'm attempting to call this function within the page (via `<script>` tags), however rather than calling it, it breaks the page. I did some digging around within the Chrome Developer Console (not sure of the name), and an error is flagged:

```
/pleaseshare/views/install/:50 Uncaught ReferenceError:updateNotification is not defined
```

However, when I pan within the console, I can clearly see the file `notifications.js` listed under scripts, and the function is defined there. If I define the function within the current scope (e.g. the line above the call), it works fine.

**What I've tried**

The function contains some javascript that requires jQuery, so I've attempted both with and without encasing it in `$(document).ready( function() {});`, with neither seeming to have any affect.

I'm pretty stumped.

For good measure, here's a link to show the structure of my javascript and html: http://snippi.com/s/znk6xe9

Any help in figuring out why this is happening, or explanations of why javascript functions cannot be called cross-file (although I'd hope this isn't the case), would be greatly appreciated ;)!!

Comment: Are you loading all of the required files into the page?

Comment: Yes, I am - http://snippi.com/s/nrwy83m

Comment: Then it should work. Maybe check that those files you are `require`ing actually load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. The issue was definitely multi-faceted, but I figured it out.

First off the use of RequireJS had an impact on `updateNotification()`, in that it couldn't be called cross-file, and was therefore considered undefined. I assume this because of how RequireJS loads files, and I'll look into the documentation later (and post an edit if I find anything relevant).

Secondly, `updateNotification()` would again be considered undefined when encased within jQuery's DOM ready loader `$(document).ready(function(){})`. However `updateNotification()` contains executions which require jQuery, so I had to encase the contents of the function in `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

This is an issue very unique to RequireJS/jQuery, hence why in most use cases this wouldn't occur.

*Side note: The tags are edited to reflect this.*

Answer (score 1):

A function cannot be called unless it was defined in the same file or one loaded before the attempt to call it.

A function cannot be called unless it is in the same or greater scope then the one trying to call it.

You code looks like the structure should work, but is clearly a reduced test case that has been reduced to the point where it won't.

Comment: Hmm :/. Is there any chance you could further explain what you mean by a reduced test case that's been reduced to the point where the structure won't work?

Comment: @Avicinnian — Copy/pasting your test case won't work because you have replaced a bunch of code with vague comments about what used to be there, and have lost the directory structure in the transfer to a flat file.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import your script into your page:

`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="path/to/notifications.js"></script>`

This needs to be added **above** the `<script>` tag that calls `updateNotification()`

Comment: I should have made myself a bit clearer, sorry about that :). I am importing it above (in between the `<head>` tags), I thought that everyone would pick that up from "However, when I pan within the console, I can clearly see the file notifications.js listed under scripts, and the function is defined there. If I define the function within the current scope (e.g. the line above the call), it works fine."

Comment: @Avicinnian Have you verified that you're not getting a 404 error on the javascript file?

Comment: Nope, it loads fine. I'll attempt to call some other functions cross-file, and see what happens. I'm thinking that it might be my use of the `require.js` library, as I did try to include a Google Chart API javascript file through it, which I think loaded, but it's functions didn't work when called in another file.

Answer (score 0):

Functions do not need to be declared in the same file. In fact, *avoiding* having every declaration dumped into the global namespace is usually a concern in JavaScript.

In the sample code in the link you provided, `updateNotification` is declared as a global, so there should not be a scoping problem.

However, in the same sample, you don't show notifications.js being included. You need to import it using a `<script></script>` element *and* that element must come before the script element that includes the call to `updateNotification`. You also must include jQuery *before* notifications.js, since it uses jQuery. So you need something like:

```
<body>
    // One or two elements
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="notifications.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() {
            var json = {status : 'ok', message: 'Hello'};
            updateNotification(json);
        });
    </script>
    // All other elements
</body>
```

Comment: Take a look at this, this shows my full markup of `<head>` where it is included - http://snippi.com/s/nrwy83m